# Laravel 5.4 current id insert eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When register at Laravel using eloquent, my PK field at table users is userid [auto increment] I want to insert the current id at the same time when I run the `User::create();` to different field (`create_by` [int]) so the create_by field will be filled with the same value as the primary key field userid, like this code:

```
User::Create([
    'user_email' => $data['user_email'],
    'user_password' => bcrypt($data['user_password']),
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'department_id' => 1,
    'user_level' => 1,
    'create_date' => Carbon::now('Asia/Jakarta'),
    'create_by' => // value same as userid the PK
])
```

How to get the current id to be used in different field?

I actually try some trick to get the id like this:

```
User::insertGetId([
    'user_email' => $data['user_email'],
    'user_password' => bcrypt($data['user_password']),
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'department_id' => 1,
    'user_level' => 1,
    'create_date' => Carbon::now('Asia/Jakarta')
])
```

It was good to return the inserted id, but my expectation is I want to save the current id to the `create_by` field at the same time `user_id` was inserted, not after the data was saved.

Comment: here you want to get the id of the user which create that form or simply the id as primary key id?

Comment: i want to get the primary key id at the same time to be inputed to field create_by, but not after the data was saved, i want to input them together at the same time

Comment: I answered try it hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be its not a good way but it will work fine Try it

I am assuming db fields please review query as desired. Its a hint to work

1st need to get max id of user as

```
$users = User::whereRaw('id = (select max(`userid`) from users)')->first();
      $create_by= $users->id+1;
      //dd($create_by);
      //die;
```

If you remove commented code it will give you next id now pass this variable as

```
'create_by' => $create_by,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$user = User::create([...]);
$user->create_by = $user->id;
$user->update();
```

**Update**
You can get the last user in the database. But be aware this is not 100% safe.

```
$lastUser = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
$user = User::create([
    ...
    'create_by' => $lastUser->id + 1
]);
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but i want to get the primary key id at the same time to be inserted to the field create_by, but not after the data was saved, i want to input them together at the same time

Comment: You have to be aware that you are using autoincrement id, this means it does exist before the data is created. It autoincrements directly in SQL and that's why it's available only after inserting. Not before. If you want it before, you have to do manual `id`, not with autoincrement.

Comment: Check my update to get the latest user. THIS IS NOT 100% SAFE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
$user_save_obj = User::Create([
    'user_email' => $data['user_email'],
    'user_password' => bcrypt($data['user_password']),
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'department_id' => 1,
    'user_level' => 1,
    'create_date' => Carbon::now('Asia/Jakarta')
])

$last_inserted_id = $user_save_obj->id;

$user_update_obj = User::find($last_inserted_id);
$user_update_obj->created_by = $last_inserted_id;
$user_update_obj->save();
```